# Import dataframes of different length to mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, import

I want to import several dataframes of different lengths to a mysql table. I have already created the table and inserted the first row of data to mysql using the first dataframe. I also found out how to import more dataframes with the same amount of columns or less. But now i want to import a dataframe which has more columns than the mysql table. Is there a way to automatically add the missing columns? My other solution would be to let python compare the mysql table columns to the dataframe colums and then manually add the missing columns.

Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.read_csv('C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/02.htb', sep = "\t")

import sqlalchemy
database_username = 'root'
database_password = 'password'
database_ip       = '127.0.0.1'
database_name     = 'htb_datei'
database_connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{0}:{1}@{2}/{3}'.
                                               format(database_username, database_password, 
                                                      database_ip, database_name))
new_df.to_sql(con=database_connection, name='htb', if_exists='append')
```